# Applying a statistical test on sliding window

Tags: r, statistics, rollapply

Applying functions on rolling windows of zoo objects is normally quite straightfoward, e.g. a moving average:

```
z <- zoo(1:10, as.Date(31:40))
rollapply(z, 4, mean, align="right")
```

Now I want to do the same thing with a statistical test, i.e. apply a [Augmented Dickey-Fuller test](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/uroot/html/ADF.test.html) on each window and get the test statistic like I got the mean in the above example.

So basically I am looking for the equivalent of the following piece of code (which of course doesn't work!):

```
rollapply(z, 4, ADF.test, align="right")
```

Comment: You are apparently using the uroot package, which is [no longer on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uroot/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
z <- zoo(rnorm(100), as.Date(1:100))
rollapplyr(z, 20, adf.test)
```

In case you just want the p-value:

```
rollapplyr(z, 20, function(u) adf.test(u)$p.value)
```